# Should gradle.properties be version controlled in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, gradle

I'm devlopping an app using flutter. Should `gradle.properties` file be commited in git? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gradle.properties contains all the required information to build an app.

It is important to commit the grade.properties if you need to built an apk after the commit.

If you wish to restrict people to build an apk you can hide it.

Thank you.